# What is this linear programming trying to do?

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

Given $G=(V,E)$, let $\mathbb{R}^V$ be the set of all real vectors $x=(x_v)_{v\in V}$ where each component $x_v$ corresponds to a vertex $v\in V$. Let $Q_G$ be defined
$$Q_G:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^V\;|\;x_u+x_v\geq1\text{ for all }\{u,v\}\in E\text{ and }x_v\geq0\text{ for all }v\in V\}$$

Consider the linear program
$$\text{min}\left\{\sum_{v\in V}x_v\;|\;x\in Q_G\right\}$$
Explain what this LP is trying to do.

I was told that this is a famous graph theory problem, but I can't find the name of it.
Just interpreting the notation, I think we are summing up all the costs of the vertices denoted $x_v$ and minimizing the edge costs between vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the **minimum vertex cover** issue as explained in paragraph 4 of this clearly written [document](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/toolkit13/lecture14.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Jean Marie mentioned this is the minimum vertex cover problem, which is correct. However, the problem you formulated has no integrality constraints (e.g. $x_v\in \{0,1\}$), so it is the *linear relaxation* of the minimum vertex cover problem. So answering your question, it is trying to find a fractional minimum vertex cover.